# No enclosing instance of type MySuperClass<B> is available due to some intermediate constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor, inner-classes

I was trying to use an inner class of the super type, which was using generics. And got that strange error above.

```
class MySuperClass<B> {
   class InnerClass {
   }

   MySuperClass(InnerClass... c) {
   }
}
```

In the sub class I tried to instantiate it:

```
class MySubClass extends MySuperClass<String> {
   MySubClass() {
      super(new InnerClass(), new InnerClass());
   }
}
```

The compiler confused me with

```
No enclosing instance of type MySuperClass<B> is available due to some intermediate constructor
```

Why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Heh, and found the answer myself:

The InnerClass is not static thus an instance of MySuperClass must be passed for the this$ reference - but that's not available *before* the super() call... simply making InnerClass static solved my problem.

Comment: +1 for finding the reason, but if 'InnerClass' is static there is no point in passing more than one instance - or any instance, for that matter. To be honest, passing an instance of an inner class to a constructor seems bad design to me.

Comment: I simplified the example, of course. It is a class to pass pairs of configuration elements (similar to Map.Entry).