# Java Inner Classes: extends keyword for multiple

Tags: java, constructor, instance, subclass, extends

I have multiple levels of inner classes. The extend keyword works for the first sub-level, but not the second. Meaning:

```
public class A{
       .........
    public class B extends A{
           ..........
        public class C extends B{
             ........
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an error for `public class C extends B{`. It says:

`No enclosing instance of type A is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation.`

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? I thought the default constructors would deal with this.

Comment: You have to make the B class Static to solve the problem . Go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703812/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-mysuperclassb-is-available-due-to-some-intermedi

Comment: How are you compiling this code? It doesn't compile in Eclipse, but is compiles fine with simple `javac`. Example http://ideone.com/LeQ7cx

Comment: check whether you need non-static inner classes at all - good explanation [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238782/why-prefer-non-static-inner-classes-over-static-ones)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is legal and should work. The fact you've got the error means one of:

1. You've posted not all the code
2. You use broken/modified jre.

I looked at your error that states

> No enclosing instance of type A is available **due to some intermediate
>   constructor invocation**.

So I suppose there are some constructors declared in your code. Possible reason of your failure is you declared constructor with parameters for class `A` but haven't done that for `B` and `C`. Explanation from [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly
>   declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor
>   that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.

---

Another possibility is that you already have `A` or `B` class in your package or you have `import`ed `A` or `B` class from another package.
The error can be misleading if compiler doesn't know what class do you extend.

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-static subclasses, which require references to outer instances. If you don't need their non-staticness just add the static keyword to the inner classes' definitions. I'm not sure why the given example isn't working for you though.

Comment: "*Java doesn't let you nest these*" that is wrong. It compiles fine if we use standard compiler. I suspect that OP is using Eclipse and its compiler apparently has problem with it. Working example http://ideone.com/LeQ7cx

Comment: Not quite, your answer doesn't really answer the question (as you said "*I'm not sure why the given example isn't working for you though*"). Since his code is valid it means that it is bug in OP's IDE, so posts without explanation about what is causing this bug and how to fix it aren't really answers. Best kind-of-answer we can post now is "it is a bug, report it".

Comment: @Pshemo I'm just trying to be helpful. It isn't really possible to debug the real problem without more information. In my opinion, the OP has posted a flawed, simplified, example without testing it.

Comment: I am not saying that you are not helpful, I am just saying that this informations shouldn't be post as an answer. We can be helpful also by posting comments. "It isn't really possible to debug the real problem without more information" 100% agree, that is why I voted to close this question until OP will provide more informations.

Comment: @Pshemo gottcha, I think we're on the same page